# StyleFrame (or styleframe?) import issue

Tags: styleframe

This is not a deal breaker but I used to import this library via "import StyleFrame", but now it throws the error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StyleFrame'**

Switching from "import StyleFrame" to "import styleframe" fixes the problem, but just wanted to know if this was done intentionally by the creator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it was done intentionally and is mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) as one of the changes between versions 2.X and 3.X:

> 3.0.1
>
> ...
>
> - Renamed package name to `styleframe` (all lowercase) in accordance of
>   PEP8
>
> ...